# Angular 6 get object from nested array by id

Tags: angular, typescript, nested, find, components

I have course array which contains courses, and every course contains array of segments. I have specific course I got in my course-detail component, and I want to get one segment by id.

example: I have this course:

```js
course: ICourse;

course = {
    "data": [
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Introduction",
        "author": "Ofir",
        "segments": [
          { "id": 1, "name": "lesson 1", "segment_type": "video", "data:" "www.hey.com/1" },
          { "id": 2, "name": "lesson 2", "segment_type": "video", "data:" "www.hey.com/1" },
          { "id": 3, "name": "lesson 3", "segment_type": "video", "data:" "www.hey.com/1" },
          { "id": 4, "name": "quiz 1", "segment_type": "quiz1", "questions": [
                                                                   {"id":1, "name":"q1"}] },
        ]
    ]
}
```

**EDIT: [click here](https://image.ibb.co/hDHnVe/Screen_Shot_2018_08_05_at_15_43_31.png) to see the JSON respond I get from the sever**

and I have segment id 4. What I want is a way to get segment object. this what I did until now (it's not working and not displaying errors):

**course.ts**

```js
export interface ICourse {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  autor: string;
  segments: ISegment[];
}

export interface ISegment {
  id: number;
  unit_id: number;
  unit_title: string;
  name: string;
  type: string;
  data: string;
  questions: IQuestion[];
}

export interface IQuestion {
  id: number;
  question: string;
  answer1: string;
  answer2: string;
  answer3: string;
  answer4: string;
  correct: number;
}
```

**course-play.component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Routes, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { LocalStorage } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';

import { ICourse } from '../course';
import { CourseService } from '../course.service';


// Couse-play decorator
@Component({
  selector: 'lg-course-play-course-play',
  templateUrl: './course-play.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-play.component.sass']
})

export class CoursePlayComponent implements OnInit {
  errorMessage: string;
  course: ICourse;
  courseId: number;
  public currentSegment: ISegment;

  constructor(private courseService: CourseService,
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private router: Router) {
         courseService.courseId$.subscribe( courseId => {
           this.courseId = courseId;
         })
    }

    // On start of the life cycle
    ngOnInit() {
        // save this course id from course-detail and get http request from the service
        this.courseId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("courseId"))
        this.getCourse(this.courseId);

        // get the current segment id to use it on the html file
        //const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        //getCurrentSegment(id);

        console.log(this.currentSegment.id);
      }

      // Get course detail by id
      getCourse(id: number) {
          this.courseService.getCourse(id).subscribe(
            course => this.course = course,
            error  => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
            const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'),
            getCurrentSegment(id)
          );
        }

      // search in course single segment by id and save it in currentSegment
      // to use it in the html file
      getCurrentSegment(id: number){
          this.currentSegment = this.course.segments.find(d => d.id === id);
      }
}
```

**html file**
[and this is the screenshot of the webpage](https://image.ibb.co/eo44tz/Screen_Shot_2018_08_05_at_16_31_15_2.png)

```html
  <div class="row content" *ngIf="course">
    <!-- Side nav-bar -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <!-- Image Logo -->
      <div id="head_sidebar">
        <img src="./assets/images/lg-white.png" class="d-inline-block align-top logo" alt="" routerLink="/courses" style="outline: none">
        <h3>{{course.title}}</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12 sidenav">
        <!-- Menu elemets -->
        <div class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" *ngFor="let unit of course.segments | groupBy: 'unit_title'; let i = index">
          <h6 class="course_play_title">Unit {{ i+1 }}: {{ unit.key }} </h6>
          <ul *ngFor="let lesson of unit.value">
            <li class="course_play_item">
              <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/courses/{{course.id}}/segments/{{lesson.id}}" (click)=getCurrentSegment(lesson.id)>{{lesson.name}} </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Body -->
    <div class="col-md-9 no-gutters" *ngIf="currentSegment">
      <div class="col-md-12 course_play_body text-center" id="#lesson">
        <h1>{{currentSegment.name}}</h1>
        <p class='sub-text' *ngIf="course.segments?.length > 0">lesson {{currentSegment.id}} of {{course.segments?.length}}</p>
        <hr>
        <iframe *ngIf="currentSegment.segment_type === 'Video'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" src="{{currentSegment.data}}"></iframe>
        <!-- <iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" src="{{segment.data}}"></iframe> -->
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: your JSON is not valid

Comment: I get the JSON from a backend server but I wrote fake data because I have a lot of data. in my backend I have course model who has many segments, and segment mode who has many questions

Comment: ok check the data is it an object or array?

Comment: segments is an array in course. I'll add a photo of the json I get from my server

Comment: Change *ngIf as <iframe *ngIf="currentSegment.type === 'Video'"

Answer (score 1):

The JSON is invalid, but I assume that `data` is an object, not an array.

You can use the `find` function of arrays to find the first element that matches.

In this case, we use `(c) => c.id === 4` to create a function that returns `true` as soon as it finds an item with an id that equals 4

```js
let course = {
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Introduction",
        "author": "Ofir",
        "segments": [
          { "id": 1, "name": "lesson 1", "segment_type": "video", "data": "www.hey.com/1" },
          { "id": 2, "name": "lesson 2", "segment_type": "video", "data": "www.hey.com/1" },
          { "id": 3, "name": "lesson 3", "segment_type": "video", "data": "www.hey.com/1" },
          { "id": 4, "name": "quiz 1", "segment_type": "quiz1", "questions": [
                                                                   {"id":1, "name":"q1"}] },
        ]
    }
}

let result = course.data.segments.find((c) => c.id === 4);

console.log(result)
```

You also need to ensure that you dont call `getCurrentSegment` until `this.course` is defined. Try this

```
ngOnInit() {
    // save this course id from course-detail component and get request from service
    this.courseId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("courseId"))
    this.getCourse(this.courseId);

    this.courseService.getCourse(this.courseId).subscribe(
        course => {
            this.course = course;
            const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
            this.getCurrentSegment(this.course, id);
        },
        error  => this.errorMessage = <any>error
      );
  }
```

Comment: I tried it but I got an error "getCurrentSegment is undefined (I wrote a function for it)

Comment: So where are you calling it from? That errors means it can't find your function...

Comment: I'm calling it in OnInit and define it in the class. I added the code in the original post

Comment: @OfirSasson It should be `this.getCurrentSegment(this.course, id);`

Comment: I did it but it's still not working. I changed to: this.currentSegment = course.segments.find(d => d.id === id); in the function but still not working

Comment: @OfirSasson When you say it's not working, what's happening? Are you getting an error? IN the code above you've got it as `course.filter( d => d.id === id).segments;` which is incorrect

Comment: Hang on, I've just spotted that `getCourse` is asychronous. You can't call `getCurrentSegment` until `this.course` is defined... I;ve edited my answer to show what I mean

Comment: if I just changed it and get only the id? like that:       getCurrentSegment(id: number){
          this.currentSegment = this.course.segments.find(d => d.id === id);
          console.log(currentSegment.id);
      }

Comment: @OfirSasson What do you mean?

Comment: ok I just edit OnInit and added the call for the function in getCourse and now I don't have any errors, but nothing is displaying. I added the div of the html file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177441/discussion-between-user184994-and-ofir-sasson).